# asp.net mvc 3, glimpse and null reference error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I installed glimpse a few days ago. Ever since I installed it I get this weird error that pops up every once in a while. I am not sure if the error is because of glimpse or was it glimpse that reveal the error to me. Any hows, if any one has a clue what can be this error all about and how can I solve it, I highly appreciate the help!!!!

the stack:

```
   at System.Web.HttpContextWrapper..ctor(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Glimpse.AspNet.AspNetFrameworkProvider.get_HttpRequestStore()
   at Glimpse.Core.Framework.GlimpseRuntime.GetTabStore(String tabName)
   at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.TabSetupContext.GetTabStore()
   at Glimpse.AspNet.GlimpseTraceListener.get_FirstWatch()
   at Glimpse.AspNet.GlimpseTraceListener.InternalWrite(String message, String category)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.TraceEvent(TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String format, Object[] args)
   at Elmah.ErrorMailModule.ReportError(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Comment: What is the actual error type/message? This call stack does run through Glimpse, so it looks like there may be a issue with Glimpse but we'll need to know the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been verified as a bug in Glimpse.

You can [track the progress of the fix on the Glimpse GitHub Issue Tracker](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/248).

I expect this bug to be fixed within the next few days and available in the [nightly builds](http://www.myget.org/F/glimpsenightly/) and [next release](http://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse/).

**UPDATE Feb 13 2013**

This issue has now been fixed and will be available in Glimpse 1.0 stable, which will be out shortly. If you'd like to use it right way, grab the [nightly build](http://www.myget.org/F/glimpsenightly/) from Feb 13+.